# Dynamic, Forum/Message Board Type, Navigation?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, random, navigation

I don't know what it's called, so I couldn't really search for it, so I apologize.

I'm looking to do navigation similar to forum thread pages. Basically how it has the...  |< < > >|

I want to implement it in a page with a dynamically generated table with data and cut off at so many rows, then use the navigation for accessing more rows.

Also, has anyone done something like this while using JQuery's TableSorter plugin? How would it work with that? (I assume it's limited to the current page, which would be unfortunate.

Anyways, thanks for the help. Even knowing wtf it's called would be useful.

Comment: Whats WTF do you mean WCF and theres WPF if you use DataGrid Paging is also one of the properties you can setup at design time as well

Comment: It's called Paging, if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like TableSorter has a Paging plugin you could use for this.

http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-pager.html

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("table") 
    .tablesorter({widthFixed: true, widgets: ['zebra']}) 
    .tablesorterPager({container: $("#pager")}); 
});
```